How to calculate the diffusion length in modulation doping?
I have read a paper(dx.doi.org/10.1021/nl201206d) about an application of modulation doping in bulk thermoelectric materials, in this paper, the nanoparticles diffuse carriers to the host materials, and I want to estimate the diffusion length from nanoparticles to the host. I know the formula $L=\sqrt{D\tau}$, $D$ is the diffusion coefficient and $\tau$ is the life time of carriers. But in modulation doping, the carriers in the host do not have recombination, and I don't know how to get the life time and diffusion length.
I have tried to simplify this problem to an electromagnetic problem, and I got a too small diffusion length to believe. I used the formula:$E=\frac{Qe}{4\pi\epsilon}(\frac{1}{R}-\frac{1}{r})$. $E$ is the band offset between materials of host and nanoparticle, $a$ is the radius of the nanoparticles, $R-a$ is the diffusion length, and $Q$ is the amount of electricity in a nanoparticle.
How to estimate a correct length?

Please explain what you mean  by "host". A picture of the modulation doped structure would be helpful to understand your question.

Modulationdoped samples are made of two types of nanograins (a two-phase composite), where dopants are incorporated only into one type, and the "host" is the undoped one. By band engineering, charge carriers could be separated from their parent grains and moved into undoped grains, which would result in enhanced mobility of the carriers in comparison to uniform doping due to a reduction of ionized impurity scattering.

In this problem, what do you need a diffusion length for? You don't need that for the calculation of the equilibrium charge carrier distribution in modulation doped structures. In a first rough approximation, you only need to solve the Poisson equation combined with the equilibrium Fermi-Dirac statistical distribution of the carriers assuming the usual densities of states of the semiconductors. That's also been done in the cited paper. A more elaborated approach would be to base the charge distribution calculation on the quantum mechanical  wave functions of  the size-quantized carrier states in the "host material". I suggest that you first study the principle of modulation doping in a simple planar heterostructure, preferably in a textbook. You could then try to extend it to the (spherical) 3-D case. Diffusion length (diffusion and recombination of minority carriers) doesn't play any role here.

Thank you for your answer. Actually, my advisor assigned me the task of roughly estimating the order of magnitude of the diffusion length to ensure the the idea worked, (although it has been used in many articles). Personally, I am also interested in understanding the specific factors that affect the diffusion length and their calculation methods, (especially in the context of modulation doping). My advisor mentioned that someone might have calculated this in the past, but I have been unable to find the relevant publication.

I dont't know what your advisor means by "diffusion length". Certainly not something with that name in semiconductor physics. The more appropriate characteristic length in this problem is the so-called Debye shielding length.

Look into the "Supporting Information" for the article you cited. The equations S1. S2. S3 are sufficient to calculate the simple carrier density problem. And there is no "diffusion length" involved.

@orz Could it be that your advisor meant "depletion length"? This practical length is usually a multiple of the Debye length and could play a role. Its estimate is also pure electrostatics, no diffusion and recombination.

Maybe “diffusion length” just means how far the carrier can travel in the "host material". My advisor also asked me to calculte  how much  the carrier concentration drop per nanometer, I think these two questions are equivalent.

I tried to calculate Debye length by $L=\sqrt{\epsilon kT/Ne^2}$, and the result is very small.
